# Union mounts not supported by the 3.8 kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I've been using union mounts (unionfs) for live images and read-only rootfs images. But when I updated the kernel to 3.8, I found that there were no config items related to overlayfs.

So the 3.8 kernel doesn't support a union mount?

Are there any alternatives to achieve a union mount in 3.8?

Comment: This is clearly a better fit for superuser.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 0):

Which distro and version, and where did you get the new kernel from?

[unionsfs](http://unionfs.filesystems.org/) is not part of the kernel proper, if you build your own kernel you must add it as a patch.

Many distros (including Ubuntu) add it to their kernel, especially if they have a *Live CD* option.

If you are using [UnionFsFuse](http://podgorny.cz/moin/UnionFsFuse) it's possible there's some incompatibility with recent kernels.